# Touching issue: Creating a filename from 2 variables

Tags: bash, shell, directory, filenames, touch

I am trying to create a filename from 2 variables.

This is the error msg:

```
touch: cannot touch `/root/tinstalls/2--06/06/15': No such file or directory
2--06/06/15 19:54
```

This is the code:

```
tdate=$(date '+%D %R')
tfile=$(echo "${toadd}--${tdate}")
touch /root/tinstalls/${tfile}

 echo $tfile
```

The directory is there.

Comment: To touch `/root/tinstalls/2--06/06/15 19:54`, you need to have directory `/root/tinstalls/2--06/06` previously.  Is it what you intended?  And you need to quotes paths which include spaces.

Answer (score 8):

[@Theophrastus has the right idea.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/208040/3645) According to [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/basedefs/xbd_chap03.html#tag_03_169) "[t]he characters composing the [file] name may be selected from the set of all character values **excluding the slash character** and the null byte" (my emphasis). In other words, every string *between* two slashes ([except the empty string](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/basedefs/xbd_chap03.html#tag_03_266)) is another directory, and you *cannot* create a file with a name containing slashes. So when you try to `touch /root/tinstalls/2--06/06/15`, the system is trying to create the file `15` inside the directory with the absolute path `/root/tinstalls/2--06/06`.

A simple way to amend this would be to replace all slashes in the filename, for example with underscore:

```
touch "/root/tinstalls/${tfile//\//_}"
```

Answer (score 2):

touch can't make directories.  For instance
[see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4711465/using-touch-to-create-directories)

I see you have "The directory is there." but you do realize that your date format includes "/" characters which would require more directories, yes?

Answer (score 2):

As others have already explained, the problem is that the slashes in your `date` make `touch` try to create a directory. Since it can't, it complains. The simplest solution is to change your date format. Instead of this:

```
$ date '+%D %R'
06/07/15 13:47
```

Use this:

```
 $ date '+%F %R'
 2015-06-07 13:52
```

Or, even better, avoid having to deal with spaces and use this:

```
$ date '+%F-%R'
2015-06-07-13:52
```

Finally, if you insist on having spaces, you must quote the name when passing it to `touch`

```
touch /root/tinstalls/"${toadd}--$(date '+%F %R')"
```

Answer (score 0):

@Theophrastus has the right idea. According to POSIX "[t]he characters composing the [file] name may be selected from the set of all character values excluding the slash character and the null byte" (my emphasis). In other words, every string between two slashes (except the empty string) is another directory, and you cannot create a file with a name containing slashes. So when you try to touch /root/tinstalls/2--06/06/15, the system is trying to create the file 15 inside the directory with the absolute path /root/tinstalls/2--06/06.

A simple way to amend this would be to replace all slashes in the filename, for example with underscore:

```
touch "/root/tinstalls/${tfile//\//_}"
```